# How to access a table which created by a new "scaffold" in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, scaffold

I use rails g scaffold to create a new group of controller, model and view, which allows users to input a int number. They can only edit the only number but not create a new one or delete it.

```
rails g scaffold number numa:integer
```

I would like to monitor what users input, and compare the number and call a function in another controller which I have already created before. However, I am quite new to rails on ruby, and do not have any idea about how to do that？

What I am pretty sure is that what users input will be stored in the a table which is bind with the new scaffold. The table's name is 'numbers', and the only inputbox for the only number's name is "numa". What should I do in another controller (lets call it "foods_controller.rb") to access the number. Maybe `numbers.numa` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I recommend popping through the [Ruby on Rails guide to ActiveRecord](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html)

To specifically answer your question, a couple of different options:

You can monitor the table contents through your model. (More preferable, probably)

Try opening up a rails console (`rails console`, `rails c`, or `irb`), and typing in `Number.all`, which will return a list of all Number records stored in the table. There are many other queries which can accomplished this way; check out the [ActiveRecord::Base API doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html) for more info.

OR

You can perform database queries directly on the database table you created.

- For sqlite3: http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/
- For postgresql: [Install Postgresql](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Detailed_installation_guides) and use [PSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/app-psql.html) to query your database directly using SQL.

EDIT: Since you want to perform this in another controller, use the first method, calling `Number.all` to get a list of all Number records stored in your database. You can also call `Number.first`, `Number.last` or `Number.find(<number_id>)` if you only want a single record to be returned.

Comment: Thank you very much for you help. Your answer is quite useful for me. However, I cannot find a proper way to select one of variables in table. Here is the structure of my table which is generated by rails c and Number.all:

Number Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "numbers".* FROM "numbers" 
 => [#<Number id: 1, numa: 100, numb: 240, numc: 200, ....

Since I have only one row for the table because I do not allow user to create new stuff but only edit it.

How can I select the numa number? I have tried Number.find(:first, :select => "numa") but failed.. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Once you have the record, you can select individual fields from it like so:

`Number.first.numa`

Or, you could use 'pluck', which selects a single field from your table.

`Number.pluck(:numa).first`